# Procedure in Redshift Return "SELECT query has no destination for result data" Error

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift, stored-functions

I keep getting the "SELECT query has no destination for result data" error upon calling this test procedure. What am I doing wrong? I did try adding the RETURN() command prior to SELECT statement but that didn't work either.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SchemaName.SP_Testing_Creating_Procedure (OUT ColumnName VARCHAR(9)) 
AS $$  
BEGIN   
 SELECT TOP 10 ColumnName FROM SchemaName.TableName where ColumnName is not null;     
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql; 

CALL SchemaName.SP_Testing_Creating_Procedure();
```

Comment: Your procedure is running a `SELECT` command. What do you want to do with the results of that query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John mentioned you need to put the result into OUT column, examples of using `IN, OUT and INOUT` parameters you can find [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_PROCEDURE.html)

But if you need to return a few rows as a result, you have to use `refcursor`
as it's described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-result-set.html)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SchemaName.SP_Testing_Creating_Procedure (INOUT result refcursor)
AS $$
BEGIN
    OPEN result FOR
    SELECT TOP 10 ColumnName
    FROM SchemaName.TableName
    WHERE ColumnName IS NOT null;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then you can call the stored procedure in a transaction

```sql
BEGIN;
CALL logs.SP_Testing_Creating_Procedure('mycursor');
FETCH ALL FROM mycursor;
COMMIT;
```

another option is temp table which is also described in the above doc

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure is running a `SELECT` command, but it is not doing anything with the results.

If your intention was to return a result set, you will need to put data in the `OUT` column.

See: [Returning a result set - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-result-set.html)